# Bootstrap row Map Width Maximization

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm looking for a way to maximize a map inside a Bootstrap row.  In the following syntax, the left `col-md-9` div is the map, and the right side is a fixed 240px wide image.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div id="mapid" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <p id="delta">
        <%= @myimage %>
        <br>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

With a fluid layout, it can get ugly quickly.  Is there a way to maximize the map in a fluid layout?  I want the map to increase with the fluidity and the image retaining 240px with a small margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do it with *flexbox*, and there are utilities from *Bootstrap* you can use: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/

```html
<div class="d-md-flex flex-md-row flex-md-nowrap align-items-md-start">
    <!-- map -->
    <iframe />

    <!-- image -->
    <img />
</div>
```

Since the map/iframe is setup as 100% width, normally this will push the other item off the row. But with *flexbox*, by default, the flexbox children have `flex-shrink: 1;` turn on. That means it will shrink for you. That's how you can get the width maximization for the map.

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/x56ao2pz/8/

Comment: OK I never even saw this.  So given two "columns" down a row, the second column can be fixed all the way down, and the first remain flexible?

Comment: I need another question.

Comment: Bootstrap rows and columns are doing the same thing! It's just that the columns have width pre-defined, and they have paddings / gutters.

Comment: OK I'm needing to pack in more info down the "fluid column" and more fixed-width down the right side column.  I'm designing another question for that.